# "react-functional-component" is anything but functional

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

This is just a minor nitpick but React has [*"function components"*](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components), not **functional** components.

Can we please rename this tag to [react-function-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-function-component)?

Comment: Calling them functional components is common enough (whether or not it is the correct term) that I think a synonym would make sense in addition to the merge (rename). The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67866230/3) and [excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67866231/3) were already corrected some time ago, but the tag name stayed in place.

Comment: Should it also be made plural? cc @HenryEcker

Comment: It would be more in line with the majority of our tags if it were plural. That said, if the tag becomes [react-function-components] then [tag:react-component] should also be made plural ([react-components]) @CodyGray

Comment: Confusing or not, isn't that the name they go by? From *[Functional Components vs Class Components in React](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/functional-components-vs-class-components-in-react/)*: *"There are mainly two components in React: Functional Components and Class Components ... Functional Components ... Sometimes referred to as “dumb” or “stateless” components as they simply accept data and display them in some form"* How is it not functional? Due to side effects (not pure functional)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen no, it isn't. I've linked to the actual React documentation